# Some records (not all!) return null from Laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm desperate. It's about this model relationship:

```
   public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\InvoiceCustomer', 'invoice_id', 'id');
    }
```

When I execute the query, I get three results. Two with the correct relationship of the InvoiceCustomer model, but one result is always  *****customer: null*****.

```
Invoice::whereHas(['customer'])->get();
```

The *invoice.id* field value is exactly eloquent with *invoice_customers.id* in the database.

That's the db schema of the two tables:

DB: **invoice_customers**

```
Schema::create('invoice_customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignUuid('invoice_id')->references('id')->on('invoices')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->string('number');
            $table->string('salutation');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('street');
            $table->string('house_number');
            $table->string('postcode');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

DB: **invoices**:

```
Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->foreignUuid('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->string('number');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->timestamp('date');
            $table->decimal('total');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->json('additional_data')->default('{}');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I hope someone have an idea or maybe had such a problem before.

I am grateful for every answer. If you need anything else, please let me know. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

`whereHas` accepted first param as `string` not `array` so

```
Invoice::whereHas('customer',function($query){

})->get();
```

Since you dont have any condition in relationship so you can use has

```
Invoice::whereHas('customer')->get();
```

or

```
Invoice::has('customer')->get();
```

Better option in your case is `has()`

For Ref:

```
  /**
     * Add a relationship count / exists condition to the query with where clauses.
     *
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @param  \Closure|null  $callback
     * @param  string  $operator
     * @param  int  $count
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
     */
    public function whereHas($relation, Closure $callback = null, $operator = '>=', $count = 1)
    {
        return $this->has($relation, $operator, $count, 'and', $callback);
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry! Thank you for your answer! I tried something out and replace it. I originally used `with('customer')`, but unfortunately it didn't work with that either.

Comment: @user16327873 then you have to use Invoice::with('customer')->has('customer')->get(); so it return only those invoices which has  customer